# Dompdf reset page count for multiple documents in same pdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I am using Dompdf to generate an invoice, which is working like a charm when printing individual invoices. Now I want it to generate a single PDF for multiple invoices. The only issue I'm having is with page numbers.

I want the page count for every invoice and currently have a counter for all pages. How does one reset the `PAGE_COUNTER` so i can get the page_count for each invoice?

My current code:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($invoice_html);
// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$canvas->page_text(490, 800, "Page: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}",$font, 9, array(0,0,0));
$file_pdf= $dompdf->output();
$file_pdf= addslashes($file_pdf);
$dompdf->stream("Invoice - ".$file['numinvoice'].".pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
```

Thank you.

Comment: The correct answer for your ask seems to be here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043592/dompdf-page-script-variables